# Android Kotlin RecycleView must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin

I use kotlin to write Andriod,but I meet a problem.

First,this is my code

```
val memoriesOfGroup = initData()
val adapter = MemoriesFrameAdapter(memoriesOfGroup, this@MainActivity)

main_memories_recycle_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
main_memories_recycle_view.adapter = adapter
```

`main_memories_recycle_view` is my RecycleView Id, I am sure it is right.

when I run app,meeting a problem.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: main_memories_recycle_view must not be null
 at me.chiaohou.love.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.kt:66)
```

the column 66 is `main_memories_recycle_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/main_memories_recycle_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is my recycle layout!

So,where is my code wrong?

Comment: have you got main_memories_recycle_view as in id anywhere else in your project?

Comment: not,but code written in `onOptionsItemSelected`, this is any influnence?

Comment: can you post your layout code also?

Comment: Yes, I post below! @Vishu

Comment: this looks fine. The code you have posted is from activity or fragment?  Can you also post imports of your activity?

Comment: ehh,the `recycleView` is designed in Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

I use `RecyleView` in `Fragment`.

So, I must use it in Fragment class.

Comment: what was your solution??